# Accessing XAMPP/laravel home page

Tags: windows, laravel, apache, ubuntu, xampp

So, i have a little issue here, i installed XAMPP which uses Apache on a Ubuntu desktop Virtual machine(on vbox), i also created a Laravel project on it and it works fine when i access it from the same VM itself ! 
[Accessing the home page from firefox ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CWwi.png)

however when i try to access it from my host windows machine it just access to the XAMPP home page like this :

[access from chrome windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbVJd.png)

now my ubuntu VM has its address set to 192.168.1.50 and my windows 192.168.1.8 ! 
i also added to the windows machine "etc" file the entry :

192.168.1.50 usthbcloud.com

and to my ubuntu machine:

127.0.0.1 usthbcloud.com

my httpd.conf file of the XAMPP includes the file : httpd-vhosts.conf

i modified the httpd-vhosts.conf to the following :

[vhosts.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbuT7.png)

Any solutions ?..

Comment: Why don't you just use php artisan serve?

Comment: Honestly, i'm new to webdev, i was following the php practionner course from Laracasts.com and he employed to download mampp, wampp or xampp to make things easier and then i jumped to the laravel course, since i'm working on my final studies project (it's actually more cloud related than webdev, it's just an interface i'm developing) i used XAMPP to have the full package installed at once !

Comment: Set your directory path to your project folder path in **httpd-vhosts.conf**

Comment: i did, my project folder is called PFE as it's shown in the vhosts.conf image!

Comment: @A.oussama Your **Directory** path and **DocumentRoot** should be same

Comment: i honestly don't know, i thought it was two different entities,  it's now working thanks to @Ashutosh answer, tho i didn't change the path !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You're Facing issues in windows. Try this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/XAMPP/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/XAMPP/htdocs/eduguru/public/"
    ServerName eduguruacademy.com
</VirtualHost>
```

> Try this in your `httpd-vhosts.conf`. Replace with your **DocumentRoot** & **ServerName** Accordingly. Then restart XAMPP

Comment: thanks, i guess i deleted these two when i started configuring the file (because i had some issues before that), i thought they were just an example on how my file should be since they had example.com ! now it's working ! 

PS: the issue was in the ubuntu, i added that to the httpd-vhosts.conf  located on the xampp folder installed in the ubuntu machine :) 

Thank you, i appreciate it :)